# Hier ist Aufräumen angesagt - groß oder klein?

Tags: nominalization

In diesem Satz bin ich unsicher, ob die Substantivierung des Verbs *aufräumen* korrekt ist:

> Die im Laufe der Zeit eingefügten Klammerbemerkungen haben den Text 
>   unlesbar gemacht, hier ist Aufräumen angesagt.

Ich habe einen sehr ähnlichen Satz wirklich benutzt. Absichtlich habe ich nahe an gesprochener Sprache formuliert, um die Leser aus ihrer Passivität herauszukitzeln.

#### Abgrenzung

In den folgenden Fällen ist mir klar, wann das Verb substantiviert ist:

- Hier müssen wir aufräumen.
- Wir waren beim Aufräumen.

#### Erster Ansatz

Die ["Artikelprobe"](https://www.kapiert.de/deutsch/klasse-9-10/rechtschreibung/gross-und-kleinschreibung/gross-und-kleinschreibung-nominalisierung-von-verben/), auf den gegebenen Fall angewendet, liefert mir ein etwas *schales* Ergebnis:

- Hier ist *ein* Aufräumen angesagt.

Analog erschiene u.a. mir Folgendes:

- Da hieß es Aufräumen. (aber: ''Da hieß es aufzuräumen.'' Oder liege ich hier falsch?)

Meine Suche nach dieser Konstellation (und Variationen davon) war aber bislang erfolglos.

#### Interessanter Fund

Ich sehe gerade beim Versuch das Wort [wie ein Substantiv zu erweitern](https://gfds.de/verben-substantivierte/), dass die von mir bemühte Analogie offenbar nicht greift (es gibt keinen Punkt 4):

1. Hier ist *heftiges Aufräumen* angesagt.
2. *Oder:* Hier ist *heftig aufräumen* angesagt.
3. *Aber:* Da hieß es *heftig aufräumen*. (ohne oder)

#### Frage

Ist das Verb hier substantiviert aufzufassen oder nicht?

Und vor allem: Wie kann ich in solchen Fällen vorgehen, um es selbst herauszufinden?

Comment: Großgeschrieben, also Aufräumen. Wenn du ein "das" vor das Wort stecken kann, ist es nicht ein Verb.

Comment: @sermonionx Die Artikelprobe kann auch zu falschen Schlüssen führen. Und man kann nicht einfach das Wort "das" in die Hand nehmen und drauf los probieren. So ist z.B. der Satz *Wann er das aufräumen wird, ist ungewiss.* absolut korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Das muss ein Substantiv sein, wenn ein Satzsubjekt sonst nicht zu finden ist, falls Subjekte zwingend notwendig sind für korrekte Grammatik. Das scheint mir der Fall zu sein.

Dass es keinen Artikel führt, schadet nicht (vgl. "Grammatik" im vorigen Satz), aber unmöglich falsch klingt dein Bsp. mit Artikel auch nicht.

Zwar könnte man versuchen das *Hier* als Subjekt zu sehen, das wäre aber wohl nicht weniger problematisch.

Vergleiche:

> Rennen ist angesagt.

```
3rd. p. sg. pass. / part. pres.
```

> Angesagt wird rennen.
>
> - Es wird Angesagt rennen.

```
???
```

letzteres erlaubt eigentlich nur eine Lösung, *Eine Person namens Angesagt rennt*.

Hochdeutsch bildet zwar keinen Präsenz im Aktiv oder sonstwas mit "ist", im Gegensatz zu Englisch (bzw. deutschen Dialekten derer ich aber nicht mächtig bin).

Allerdings ist das höchst konstruiert. Der Satzbau wäre jeweils allenfalls in Nebensätzen zu finden. Die sind widerum nicht aussagekräftig, wenn darin gar kein overtes Subjekt notwendig ist.

> - Es war Faulenzen geplant, aber angesagt ist Rennen.

Dabei würde ich durchaus zur Verb-Schreibung tendieren, da neben der Substantivierung eher das Kollektivnomen *das Rennen* "race" überwiegt, während die Itterativbildung durch Partizip--*Gerenne*--zum Ausdruck kommt, jedenfalls eher mit Artikel. Deiner Frage wird dabei also durch Substitution ausgewichen, da der Unterschied groß/klein natürlich nie zu hören ist.

Es kommt übrigens auch darauf an, welche Bedeutung gemeint ist. Der Kontrast ist relativ deutlich zu sehen in "Das Aufräumen wurde ab-gesagt". Dagegen steht *in der Mode angesagt* oder ähnlich agens-lose Formulierungen: "Bei schlechtem Wetter ist Pullover angesagt". Hochdeutsch ist das aber nicht, die Frage daher eher theoretisch.

Comment: Die Antwort steht doch im ersten Satz. Es muss das Subjekt sein. Dass es demnach konsequent großgeschrieben werden müsste, erschließt sich aus dem Kontext. Ganz richtig ist das vielleicht nicht, würde mich aber schon wundern. *Bei schlechtem Wetter ist Pullover tragen angesagt*? *Pullover-Tragen*? *das Tragen von Pullovern*? oder doch ein Verb: *pullovertragen*?

Comment: @vectory Dass ein Wort das Subjekt bildet, ist kein Grund für Großschreibung. Im Satz *Heute bleibe ich zu Hause.* ist *ich* das Subjekt.

Comment: @Wolf das ist richtig, schließlich können sogar ganze Nebensätze (also Verbalphrasen) den Platz eines Subjektes einnehmen.

Comment: Kannst du mir erklären, warum du die korrekte Schreibung *Partizip Präsens* auf die falsche *partizip presenz* zurückgesetzt hast? Ich habe - leider - insgesamt extreme Schwierigkeiten deiner Argumentation zu folgen. Vielleicht sollte ich meine Frage besser mit etwas Kontext anreichern, um klarer zu machen, was gemeint ist.

Comment: Erstens, das ist natürlich ein Rechtschreibfehler gewesen (bzw. ein Fäler im hoffnungslos inkonsisten Rächtschraepsüstem). Ich weise alle Schuld von mir, Latein zu lernen um den Unterschied zwischen prae- und *pre-* zu lernen. Zweitens, dich zwingt auch niemand, diese Antwort zu akzeptieren. Wie geschrieben würde ich persönlich auch kleinschreibung akzeptieren. Wie üblich wollte ich nur ein paar Gegenargumente liefern. Das muss nun reichen.

Comment: Was willst du eigentlich mit *falls Subjekte zwingend notwendig sind für korrekte Grammatik* ausdrücken? (Meine Frage bezieht sich schon auf *die deutschen Grammatik*.) Ich habe mit einer beschlagenen Deutschlehrerin über meinen Satz gesprochen, dabei kam u.a. heraus, dass es sogar Sätze gibt, in denen das Subjekt gar nicht ausgeschrieben steht, z.B. in Imperativformen wie "Sitz gerade!".

Comment: Du wiederholst dich. Es müsste heißen "setz dich gerade hin". "Man sitze gerade" klingt irgendwie so hochnäsig.